# Using UserControl paint event to trigger idle timer?

Tags: c#, timer, user-controls

I've been tasked with triggering a logout event after a period of inactivity. I have created some code that appears to be working in my application, but I'm assuming I took an abnormal approach as I haven't seen similar solutions proposed to others attempting to do the same. My approach relies on the UserControl.Paint event, is there a better practice? Are there limitations to the Paint event I may be unaware of?

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    private Timer _idleTimer;
    private SubControl _sc;

    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create the auto logout timer
        _idleTimer = new Timer();
        _idleTimer.Interval = 300000;
        _idleTimer.Tick += btnLogout_Click;
        _idleTimer.Enabled = true;

        // Create the subcontrol.
        _sc = new SubControl();
        _sc.Paint += (o, i) => _idleTimer.Reset(); // Extension method that call Stop and Start
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(_sc);
    }
}
```

Thanks - Derrick

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Application.Idle event instead:

```
Application.Idle += (o, i) => { _idleTimer.Reset(); };
```

The paint event isn't always firing, so it's unreliable as your source of inactivity.